# 'You rather not' construction

Tags: syntactic-analysis

What would be a correct way to say this:

> If you rather not wait, you can always do sth else.

or

> If you'd rather not wait, you can always do sth else.

And what about the comma? Is it needed here?

Answer (score 2):

The correct way would be:

> If you'd rather not wait, you could always do something else.

You can use 'can' but 'could' matches tense a little more closely.

The comma should be used to separate the two clauses, yes.